# How To Get SQLAlchemy To Connect MSSQL to AWS Using a Config File?

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

## Versions

> Mac OSX 10.13.6 (17G65)
>
> AWS RDS MSSQL Instance `Select @@VERSION;` Microsoft SQL Server 2017
>
> `python3 -V` Python 3.7.0
>
> `pip3 show Flask-SQLAlchemy` Name: Flask-SQLAlchemy V: 2.3.2
>
> `pip3 show Flask-Migrate` Name: Flask-Migrate V: 2.2.1

### config.py

```
class Config(object):
    """Docstring for Config Class."""

    SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY') or 'you-will-never-guess'
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = (os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL'))
```

### .env

```
SECRET_KEY=SuperDuperSecretPassKey
DATABASE_URL='mssql+pyodbc://DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=My-custom-route.a0aaa0000aaaa.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com;DATABASE=Databasetoconnectto;UID=JayRizzo;PWD=SuperAwesomePassword!!!'
```

## Problem:

How do I properly set the SQLAlchemy URL in my config?

1. Encoded or decoded URL?
2. Can I use a URL String?
3. Does it have to be a DSN?

### Note:

I can connect using a template and a python file directly like [Connect to MSSQL Database using Flask-SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47757299/1896134) and [even using `pyodbc` that I created.](https://github.com/JayRizzo/Random_Scripts/blob/master/pyodbc_mssqldbtest.py)

But when I use the env variable, I have gotten errors ranging from:

1. Values Must be Strings config
2. Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string '%s'" % name
3. sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('IM012', '[IM012] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]DRIVER keyword syntax error (0) (SQLDriverConnect)') (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/dbapi)
4. sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)') (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/rvf5)

I am Stumped...

Answer (score 4):

- **Can I use a URL String?**

  - Not that I have been able to get so far.
- **Encoded or decoded URL?**

  - I was NOT able to get either to work so far [even if you double encode the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47757299/1896134).
- **Does it have to be a DSN?**

  - Yes, So far that is what worked.

## USE A DSN

Well, I was able to connect using a DSN which was an interesting treat of research...

1. Check your odbcinst Drivers and configs

```bash
$ odbcinst -j 

unixODBC 2.3.7
DRIVERS............: /usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /usr/local/etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /usr/local/etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /Users/jkirchoff/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

Then View, Customize, Validate your odbcinst.ini & odbc.ini files.

### /usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini

```bash
[My_installed_ODBC_driver]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib
Driver=/usr/local/Cellar/msodbcsql17/17.2.0.1/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib
UsageCount=1
```

> Important: Please make sure that you check that the paths exist for your drivers!

.

> NOTE: Yes, I know that there are two Driver locations, the first is a symlink and the other is the actual location.  It still works with either one or both listed.  It is just here for the curious.

### /usr/local/etc/odbc.ini

```bash
[MY_Custom_DSN_NAME]
Driver              = My_installed_ODBC_driver
Description         = My Connection to AWS
Database            = MyDatabaseNameHERE
Server              = My-custom-route.a0aaa0000aaaa.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
Readonly            = No
Port                = 1433
Trace               = No
```

Make sure to match the naming conventions of your drivers `My_installed_ODBC_driver` is my example.

Then Set your .env file to contain a connection to the DSN_name as listed above would be

### [root of your flask project]/.env

```bash
DATABASE_URL='mssql+pyodbc://JayRizzo:SpaceInvaderPassword!@MY_Custom_DSN_NAME'
```

> Note: Thinking about the Linkup, it should be as follows `odbcinst.ini` supplies driver to > `odbc.ini` supplies DSN name to > `.env`[MY_Custom_DSN_NAME]

or

> the opposite `Env` file references `odbc` and it references the `odbcinst` for the driver. how ever you want to think about it.

## Finally

My_installed_ODBC_driver & MY_Custom_DSN_NAME can be any name you want. just make sure they get matched up correctly, (that was part of my issue, originally with trying the DSN.)

I am unable to use a direct connection url.

I have only been able to connect thus far by using a DSN.

Now I can use SQLAlchemy `flask db upgrade` & `flask db migrate`

Any insight would be nice.

Hope you were able to follow my logic.

### Links

[SQLAlchemy can't connect to an mssql database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15627017/1896134)